# Embed a PostgreSQL database on iOS

Tags: ios, postgresql

Is there any way to embed a PostgreSQL server in an iOS app? I am building a client/server app that needs the capability to work offline. Right now, I maintain separate sqlite and PostgreSQL backends for these two modes, but I would really like to standardize on PostgreSQL.

I understand that the architecture of PostgreSQL is not conducive to embedding, but with the increasing power of iOS devices, the case for embedding the database engine will only grow – is there any work towards making this a reality?

Comment: Why would you do this? Postgres is not intended for embedded applications and it's extremely resource hungry compared to things like SQLite. Synchronization between local and remote is always going to be a challenge, standardizing on a singular database platform makes it only marginally easier but on the whole more difficult. Postgres does not like being started and stopped randomly.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I had in mind would be to use some of the advanced GIS functionality which is best developed on this database platform. Geometry operations are intense anyway, and the PostGIS platform implements things like spatial indexes that make it more efficient for certain operations than SQLite. Still the overhead of a multiclient database _is_ large...

Comment: Postgres is not going to be a good solution here. It's like getting a bulldozer to weed your garden.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that spatialite has some topology extensions now so that may prove to be the way to go.

Comment: I like the idea, given that the AppleWatch I'm wearing is more powerful than the first computer I programmed professionally, and the phone I'm carrying has more compute power and storage than what sent Americans to the moon.  PostgreSQL is much leaner than Oracle and I love Oracle.